# How can I update a field of relational table with a data from a related table

Tags: java, grails

I need to update the value of my relational table.
I have `book_id` and `author_id` in the relational table, and I obtain the `Id`value from Book table and the `Id` value of Author table, and I want to change `author_id` from a `book_id`.

I did this using Grails but it didn't work.
I'm using the Grails framework which includes Hibernate and Spring.

```java
        Book bookToEdit = Book.findById(bookId)
        Author newAuthor = Author.findById(authorId)
        BookAuthor bookAuthor = BookAuthor.findByBook(bookToEdit)
        bookAuthor.author = newAuthor
        bookAuthor.save(flush:true)
```

When I debugged this code, submitting my changes, I receive the original Id from the author and not the change submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to edit the relationship table yourself.   If you have a Book class like:

```
class Book {
   String title
   Author author
}
```

Then you should be able to do this, and the relationship table will be updated appropriately:

```
Book bookToEdit = Book.findById(bookId)
Author newAuthor = Author.findById(authorId)
book.author = newAuthor
book.save(flush:true)
```

Comment: Thank you! Just I was trying to update the table when I wasn't putting all the necesary values.